# Extending Material Theme with Kotlin extension property doesn't work

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The official [documentations](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/themes/custom#extending-material) gave this code example:

```kotlin
// Use with MaterialTheme.typography.textFieldInput
val Typography.textFieldInput: TextStyle
    get() = TextStyle(/* ... */)
```

So I defined my own h1 style as follows

```
val Typography.h1: TextStyle
    get() = TextStyle(
        fontSize = 20.sp,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
    )
```

and use it

```kotlin
@Preview
@Composable
fun GenericEmptyState(
    @PreviewParameter(EmptyStatePreviewParameters::class) data: EmptyStateData
) {
    MaterialTheme {
        Column(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize(1f)
                .background(Color.White)
                .padding(24.dp)
        ) {
            Image(
                painterResource(data.image),
                contentDescription = "illustration",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(150.dp)
                    .padding(6.dp)
            )

            Text(data.title, Modifier.padding(6.dp), style = MaterialTheme.typography.h1)
//...
```

But the result text style I got is definitely not size 20 or bold font weight
It looks like the default h1 style in Material Theme

[image]

Can't see what's wrong myself
Can anyone?

Comment: You have `style = MaterialTheme.typography.h1`. Should that be `style = MaterialTheme.typography.h2`?

Comment: Typo due to last minute change, fixed it

Comment: Thanks @Abby, I fixed the typo, can you please undo your downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the `Typography` class itself has a member named `h1` which will be used instead of your extension. You should actually get this warning in Android studio which explains it pretty well:

> Extension is shadowed by a member: public final val h1: TextStyle

The documentation you mention is called "Custom design systems in Compose" - this is meant for someone who doesn't want to use the default `Typography` properties - either needs more text styles than provided or simply wants to name them differently. You should probably look at [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/themes/material#typography) section first - it shows how to create your own theme and override the default `Typography` styles. It should look something like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyTheme(
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    MaterialTheme(
        typography = Typography(
            h1 = TextStyle(...),
        ),
        content = content,
    )
}

@Composable
fun MyContent() {
    MyTheme {
        // MaterialTheme.typography.h1 will be your defined TextStyle here
    }
}
```

Comment: `MaterialTheme.typography.textFieldInput` looks like a legit typography type but turns out it's not. Guess I jumped the gun there. Thanks